# Как написать процедуру, которая будет удалять данные по изменяемому условию в параметрах?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, delete, procedure

Нужна процедура, которая будет принимать:

- `x` - название столбца, который надо проверить
- `y` - операция, по которой будет осуществляться проверка (<, >, =, <>)
- `z` - значение, с которым будет осуществляться проверка

Должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
create procedure deleting(x in VARCHAR2, y in VARCHAR2, z in VARCHAR2) 
is
    begin 
    if (y = '>') then
        delete from t where t.x > z;
    elsif (y = '<') then
        delete from t where t.x < z;
    elsif (y = '=') then
        delete from t where t.x = z;
    elsif (y = '<>') then
        delete from t where t.x <> z;
    end if;
end;
```

Но так не работает потому, что имя столбца `x` нельзя напрямую записать в `where`.

Comment: используйте динамический sql. типа этого `execute immediate 'delete from t where t.x > z';`. Вместо `t` подставьте имя таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с динамическим SQL. В данном случае лучше только значение для условия выделить в отдельный параметер. Пробуйте:

```sql
create table t as 
    select rownum col1, rownum*10 col2, rownum*100 col3 
    from xmlTable ('1 to 9');

create or replace procedure deleteFromT (whereCondition varchar2, value number) is
    stmt varchar2 (32000) := 'delete from t where '||whereCondition||':value'; 
begin
    execute immediate stmt using value;
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row(s) deleted.'); 
end;
/

exec deleteFromT ('col2>', 50)

4 row(s) deleted
```